# Bug with resizing panes in tmux when using ZSH

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, tmux

I am using Tmux with ZSH and have a problem when trying to resize panels.
I am currently using these bindings to resize panels as I work:

```
unbind-key M-j        ; bind-key -n M-j     resize-pane -D 1
unbind-key M-k        ; bind-key -n M-k     resize-pane -U 1
unbind-key M-h        ; bind-key -n M-h     resize-pane -L 1
unbind-key M-l        ; bind-key -n M-l     resize-pane -R 1
```

For example: I have two panels, one on top of the other and both displaying a ZSH prompt. The top panel has run the following commands:

```
perry@touriste-147-12:~% echo hello
hello
perry@touriste-147-12:~% echo goodbye
goodbye
perry@touriste-147-12:~% _
```

When vertically resizing the bottom panel to make it smaller the top panel will be enlarged to compensate as expected but the following is added to the screen:

```
perry@touriste-147-12:~%            <<<
perry@touriste-147-12:~%            <<<  THIS IS ALL NEW AND NOT CREATED 
perry@touriste-147-12:~%            <<<  BY ME
perry@touriste-147-12:~% echo hello <<<
perry@touriste-147-12:~% echo hello
hello
samperry@touriste-147-12:~% echo goodbye
goodbye
perry@touriste-147-12:~% _
```

Then if I resize the bottom panel back the same happens to the bottom, with the prompt staying at the position where it had been shrunk to like this:

From:

```
perry@touriste-147-12:~% _
```

To:

```
perry@touriste-147-12:~%
perry@touriste-147-12:~%
perry@touriste-147-12:~%
perry@touriste-147-12:~%
perry@touriste-147-12:~%
perry@touriste-147-12:~%
perry@touriste-147-12:~%
perry@touriste-147-12:~% _
```

This does not occur when resizing the window using iTerm without tmux. The zsh shell displays properly in iTerm

The same is true of Terminal

This also does not occur when using bash in tmux with the same settings

So far I have tried:

- Adding `export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8` to my .zshrc
- Setting `export TERM="xterm-256color"` and `export TERM="screen-256color"` in my .zshrc
- Using the same for `set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"`

Sadly, none of this has solved my problem.

Comment: I haven't found a solution either, but I worked around the bug by adding `if [[ ! -z $TMUX ]]; then printf '\n'; fi` to my `.zshrc`.